# Getting the numeric value of a given Windows message identifier

Tags: windows, winapi, encoding, windows-messages

The  WinAPI associates its [messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues), such as WM_GETTEXT, with ints, such as 13. Each message seems to have its own code.

Unfortunately, [this list](https://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages) of codes is incomplete. For example, it lacks the code for the message  [CB_FINDSTRING.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-findstring)

**Question:** Given a Windows message, such as CB_FINDSTRING, how can I find its numerical code? The resources I've tried don't have all of them, and I've looked around a lot.

Comment: Why do you care? If you *must* have it for whatever reason, find it where the compiler finds it, in `winUser.h`.

Comment: @dxiv I'm using it with `ctypes` in Python, which prevents me from using the message identifier itself without some import-wrangling in a way that isn't clear to me. Using ints has worked fine for me, though, hence my question

Comment: Lookup [pyWin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/master/win32/Lib/win32con.py#L1770).

Comment: @dxiv This is perfect for my purposes. Thanks!

Comment: The free online site https://www.magnumdb.com (disclaimer: I wrote it) is a tool that will give you all values you want: https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=CB_FINDSTRING (332) and also the other way around (https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=332) it's especially useful for people who are not using C/C++. pywin32 has just a small extract of what exists in Windows.

Comment: @SimonMourier Impressive! I've just bookmarked it. Feel free to write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The free online site https://www.magnumdb.com (disclaimer: I wrote it) is a tool that will give you all values you want (it has around 400000 values/name pairs extracted from the whole Windows SDK and DDK, and also some Visual Studio headers), for example:

https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=CB_FINDSTRING

[image]

It also works the other way around: https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=332

It will give you the *computed value* (you can also see the input source) and is especially useful for people who are not using C/C++.